# setTimeOut function does not call after delayed time duration everytime

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

My code for that is as shown below :

```
setTimeout(function () {
  //send message in rabbitmq queue 
}, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Here what happens is that function inside setTimeOut gets called sporadically and not every time. So how to make it call the code written inside function every-time?

Comment: This needs a lot of clarification and extra information. How are you verifying this problem (how do you **know** it's not working)? What are you seeing happen and how does that differ to what you expect?

Comment: Check out log, maybe it gets called but failing sporadically?

Comment: @dehumanizer I checked the logs and then only came to the conclusion

Comment: @MrugeshThaker This require more clarification, steps, and the exact purpose and where you are trying to add the code! without any detail no one can conclude the exact issue and it's solution.

Answer (score 2):

To understand how **setTimeout** works you need to know javascript is asynchronous and single-threaded.

**setTimeout** function executes once the stack is empty. So the execution of your function is mainly depends on when the stack becomes empty.

Event loop is the one which always check for the stack empty and give a chance to function to execute. To understand this you can check the how event loop works: http://latentflip.com/loupe

Comment: I totally agree with the stack concept for timeout function. But here what happens is , sometimes the function does not get called itself. so is there any other option better than this with guaranteed delay mechanism?

Comment: When you say sometimes, there is something happened on that time which effect the timer to stop it from execution. Need to check that condition.

Comment: I checked the error logs but I did not find any error related to that.

Comment: While this is a relevant comment, it's not an answer. It doesn't explain why the OP has their issue, how to fix it, or even provide a fix. *setTimeout* is not a "web API", it's a host method. It does not require that the host is connected to the web, or any kind of network. Perhaps you meant [*RabbitMQ*](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html).